# Is Equalizer.getNumberOfBands() always the same?

Tags: android, audiotrack, equalizer

Im developing an audio app which should include an Equalizer. For that I want to save the presets for all albums.

I just ask myself if
[Equalizer.getNumberOfBands()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#getNumberOfBands%28%29) is always the same on a single device, so I can have presets generated without fetching (and instantiating) an audiotrack first.

I could not find any useful information on the internet for that.

Answer (score 0):

The number of supported bands will vary depending on the device. 
Empirically, i can remember seeing some device with only 3 bands, many with 5 bands, and probably a few with more. 
What I cannot answer is if across many devices with the same amount of supported bands, each band are at the same exact frequency.

Comment: But the number of bands within a single device stays always the same?

Comment: Without any "rom" update, yes. But you never know what an update could bring or remove, so you'd better assume it can still change after an update.